# How to get around Flask-SQLAlchemy database session timing out (avoiding "MySQL server has gone away")

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have seen this question multiple times on here with answers that did not help me.

From my understanding, Flask-SQLAlchemy connects to the database at the beginning of the Flask request and tears down this session when done. But what if this request takes a long time?

For example, my app accepts a POST request that starts a long-running Celery task that needs to write to the database. The MySQL server "goes away" after some time, making the write back to the database at the end of the task not work.

I read online to set `options["pool_pre_ping"] = True` to mitigate such a problem (using the subclassing SQLAlchemy workaround found [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/589)), but that makes no difference. The same error occurs and it almost seems that no settings actually seem to change.

I think the solution is to rethink how the task writes to the database. Currently, I am using the same `session` from the request for the task. Any ideas if this is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the session but keep the objects around. Edit them. Then use `merge`. Make sure the setting `expire_on_commit` is `False`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea about rethinking how the task writes to the database.

It might be prudent to have the Flask route append the task to a Queue.
Once the task is in the Queue the Flask route can return, and thus the web request context will be closed.

You can then have another python (non-flask) program running in the background that continuously reads from this Queue, and pops the newest tasks from it and then executes the tasks and saves them to the database.

This can be done using  Maybe you are already doing this using Celery to call an async function?
Here's a blogpost on how to create such a Celery task and use it with a Flask route
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask

You are correct, that Flask-SQLAlchemy tears down the database session when the web request context closes, which happens when the flask route returns.

To prevent Flask-SQLAlchemy from closing your session you should not pass your `session` from the Flask route to the async Celery function. Instead you should "create a new session" (make a call to the session registry) within the celery async function.

In fact this is a general principal when using sessions from SQLAlchemy within a web app. You want to avoid passing the session object around. SQLAlchemy promotes this principal by using the Registry Pattern to create a Session Registry that returns a "thread local" session object. This idea of a "thread local" session means that when you grab a session from the Session Registry you are ensuring that the session is only used in the current thread. Since you are ultimately creating a new thread to execute the long running task you can rely on the Session Registry to give you a thread that will not be effected by the closing of the web request, as the web request is being handeled in a different thread.

Flask-SQLAlchemy implements this Session Registry by default. As an example you might have a route and celery task look like the below:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from celery import Celery

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)


@celery.task
def do_stuff_that_takes_10_minutes(payload):
    session = db.session  # Gets a thread local session from the Session Registry that is different from the session obj you used in the route because this function will be executed in its own thread.
    # some long running task here
    return result

@app.route('/long_running_task', methods=['GET'])
def long_running_task():
  session = db.session  # Get a thread local session from the Session Registry that will close once this web request is complete

  # use this session here and do stuff

  # Call this function, which Celery will spawn a new thread to do
  # Don't pass the above session object into this function, we want this
  # session obj to stay only within this thread.
  do_stuff_that_takes_10_minutes.delay()

  return "Executing task, could take 10 minutes or more."
```

Comment: This is pretty much the pattern I use with my app, but I use the MySQL database to store the task results (I want to ask about the output of them later, possibly even after the server is shut down). That is not necessary--I can switch to Redis. But, still, the Celery task needs to write other things to the database, not just the results of the tasks, but things that the task itself does. I feel I should just make the session when the database updates are ready to commit, but I'm not sure how I'm not already doing that, as I am following what you suggested, using `db.session` where needed.

Comment: I don't pass around a session anywhere. I do a long task and then `db.session.commit()` at the end of it. It gives me the error that the MySQL server has gone away.